# Как построить древовидный массив неограниченной вложенности?

Tags: php, массивы, рекурсия

Есть 2 массива. Первый массив это родители первого уровня, а второй потомки (родитель указан в ключе 'referer' ). Как их иерархически объединить в третий, при условии, что вложенность может быть условно неограниченной?

**Массив 1 (родители первого уровня):**

```
$array1 = [
    ['page'=>'1.ru', 'title'=>'—', 'childs'=>[]],
    ['page'=>'3.ru', 'title'=>'—', 'childs'=>[]],
    ['page'=>'6.ru', 'title'=>'—', 'childs'=>[]]
];
```

**Массив 2 (потомки):**

```
$array2 = [
    ['page'=>'666.ru', 'title'=>'+', 'referer'=>'66.ru'],
    ['page'=>'33.ru' , 'title'=>'+', 'referer'=>'3.ru'],
    ['page'=>'66.ru' , 'title'=>'+', 'referer'=>'6.ru']
];
```

**Массив 3 (желаемый результат):**

```
$array3 = [
    ['page'=>'1.ru', 'title'=>'—', 'childs'=>[]],
    ['page'=>'3.ru', 'title'=>'—', 'childs'=>[
        ['page'=>'33.ru' , 'title'=>'+', 'childs'=>[]],
    ]],
    ['page'=>'6.ru', 'title'=>'—', 'childs'=>[
        ['page'=>'66.ru' , 'title'=>'+', 'childs'=>[
            ['page'=>'666.ru', 'title'=>'+', 'childs'=>[]]
        ]]
    ]]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Сгруппировать дочерние элементы по родителю.

```php
$array1 = [
    ['page' => '1.com', 'child' => []],
    ['page' => '2.com', 'child' => []],
    ['page' => '3.com', 'child' => []],
];

$array2 = [
    ['page' => '1-1.com', 'referer' => '1.com'],
    ['page' => '3-1.com', 'referer' => '3.com'],
    ['page' => '3-1-1.com', 'referer' => '3-1.com'],
    ['page' => '3-1-1-1.com', 'referer' => '3-1-1.com'],
];

$groupByParents = [];

foreach ($array2 as $item) {
    $groupByParents[$item['referer']][] = $item;
}
```

2. Рекурсивно заполнить родителя потомками

```php
function fillParent(array $parents, array &$child): array
{
    foreach ($parents as &$item) {
        $item['child'] = fillParent($child[$item['page']] ?? [], $child);
    }

    return $parents;
}
```

Результат

```php
$result = fillParent($array1, $groupByParents);
```

```php
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "page" => "1.com"
    "child" => array:1 [▼
      0 => array:3 [▼
        "page" => "1-1.com"
        "referer" => "1.com"
        "child" => []
      ]
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "page" => "2.com"
    "child" => []
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "page" => "3.com"
    "child" => array:1 [▼
      0 => array:3 [▼
        "page" => "3-1.com"
        "referer" => "3.com"
        "child" => array:1 [▼
          0 => array:3 [▼
            "page" => "3-1-1.com"
            "referer" => "3-1.com"
            "child" => array:1 [▼
              0 => array:3 [▼
                "page" => "3-1-1-1.com"
                "referer" => "3-1-1.com"
                "child" => []
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```